# Android . Update main Activity display when onLocationChanged is triggered (in different class)

Tags: android, gps

I am fairly new to Android and Java programming and I am trying to build an application that requires the best current GPS position.

My approach was to create a MyLocation (based on code I found on the internet), this class sets up two listeners (GPS and Network) and has a timer, which then returns the best location at the end of the time. My problem is that I don't really know how to return the location to my main activity and to trigger a refresh of my view when the position is getting updated

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    currentLocation = location;
    Log.d("GPS Listener - OnLocationChanged", String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLatitude()));
}
```

In my main activity, I have the following
...

```
//Start Updates
if(myLocation.startUpdates(GPSTest.this)){
   ...
}

//Update Position
public void updatePosition() {
 myTextView1...
}
```

I would like to call the UpdatePosition() method in my main activity (GPSTest) when the onLocationChanged() method is triggered in MyLocation class

My idea was to use a handler and a callback, but I am not really sure how to implement this. Is that a correct approach, and if yes, any suggestion on how to implement this.

Thanks for your feed-back,

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the correct approach.

You should create handler in the main class, and define what should it do when called, and then pass it to MyLocaion class/object. in the method onLocationChanged() you should send a message to the handler (`handler.send(msg)`)

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is exactly where I don't know how to proceed. How do I create this handler and then use it from my "MyLocation" class.

Comment: You can simply create handler by:
`Handler handle = new Handler(){
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
//whatever you want to do
}`